# Why can I only ping from one direction in the beginning?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, ping

My situation is as following:

```
Linux PC (busybox)
192.168.0.0  (or 192.168.0.1)                
(running dhcp)               

Windows PC (XP 2002, service pack 2)
192.168.0.200
got the ip from dhcp
```

After booting at first:

Ping from Windows PC to Linux -> not working

Then Ping from Linux PC to Windows PC -> working

now if I Ping from Windows PC to Linux -> working. ？！

why? how could this happen?

To compare with it. I tried to ping another Linux PC(Ubuntu) with the Linux PC mentioned above. Everything worked fine.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14915309/5164855) seems to address your problem. If you change your Linux IP to `192.168.0.1`, that should resolve it. See also [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/10989/409801).

Comment: @AFH Hi. I actually tried it, still the same problem.

Comment: Do you run a firewall on Linux?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Hi. I only have two nat rules. I am not sure if it's related. But I deleted the rules. rebooted, the problem is still there...

Comment: Can you capture the traffic with Wireshark, e.g. on a mirroring port of your switch?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Hi. I connected them directly with a ethernet cable.

Comment: What about your Windows firewall? Try disabling it for your tests (disconnect from ISP if you have security concerns). Also, bear in mind that your Windows OS is over 15 years old, so you cannot expect it to handle `.0` addresses, a comparatively recent innovation. I would do all tests with `.1` to stop confusion over this point: if you get it working, then you can try reverting to `.0`, but if there are two or more things wrong you'll never see the solution even if you correct it/them.

Comment: @AFH Hi, I also tested the .1 or other addresses, nothing worked. The windows firewall is inactive.

Comment: I think it's down to WireShark now, as @ThomasWeller suggests. Linux supports promiscuous mode, and Windows 10 doesn't (I don't know about 2002), so you may need less filtering if you run WireShark on the Windows side. I don't see another option now, though WS is not easy to learn if you've not used it before. The Windows system was aware of the Linux system when it verified its IP address, so it's very puzzling. If WS is too difficult, then check the settings mentioned [here](/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all). If all else fails, add `ping -c 1 192.168.0.200` to the Linux boot sequence.